# mysql replication error: Candidate slave is missing replication user

Tags: mysql, replication

Context:
I'm trying to set up mysql replication with one master and one slave. I'm using the new GTID method in mysql 5.6, along with the mysql utilities for automatic failover.

I'm able to set up replication with a master node M and a slave node S.

I'm trying to run through a simple script to show myself that everything is set up correctly. The script is as follows:

1. Set up replication with node M as master and node S as slave
2. Ensure that changes made to tables in M are reflected in S
3. Shutdown M and ensure that S takes over as new master
4. Make a few table changes to S
5. Startup M and add it back to cluster as a slave
6. Ensure that M catches up to S with its updates
7. Make M the master node again

My script seems successful until the last step.
Largely, I'm following the steps here: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/replication-and-auto-failover-made-easy-with-mysql-utilities

But when I run "mysqlrpladmin --master=root@S_NODE --new-master=root@M_NODE --demote-master --discover-slaves-login=root switchover", I'm getting the following error:

```
# Discovering slaves for master at S_NODE
# Discovering slave at M_NODE
# Found slave: M_NODE
# Checking privileges.
# Performing switchover from master at S_NODE to slave at M_NODE
# Checking candidate slave prerequisites.
Candidate slave is missing replication user.
ERROR: Candidate slave is missing replication user.
# Errors found. Switchover aborted.
#
# Replication Topology Health:
+-----------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
| host            | port  | role    | state  | gtid_mode  | health  |
+-----------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+ 
| S_NODE          | 3306  | MASTER  | UP     | ON         | OK      |
| M_NODE          | 3306  | SLAVE   | UP     | ON         | OK      |
+-----------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
```

I can't seem to find any google or stackoverflow pages related to that error message "Candidate slave is missing replication user."

I believe I have a replication user on both node S and M, since both acted as a slave at one point in my test script.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Never used the new tools yet, but shouldn't it be `-discover-slaves-login=root:switchover"` if it's a user:pass combo?

Comment: switchover is not a password (not mine anyways). I believe it's part of the command, at least according to the examples I'm following

Comment: Ah, I see, it's _is_ a user:pass combo, but that example assumes a login 'root' without password. Are you _allowed_ to login with mysql as root without password on both of those machines from the location you run `mysqlrpladmin`? If not, you may want to set up an account which does, and may or may not have a password.

Comment: I have set up passwords to both machines and I've confirmed that I can login to both from the other. I didn't include the :password in my example for brevity

Comment: I dug into the python code and found the error line. I added  the --force flag and it seemed to work. Not sure exactly why it didn't before. I found someone who experienced the same problem but he took much more drastic measures (modifying the python files). That article was written in japanese so I wasn't comfortable trying it.

Comment: Nice, it's been resolved ;) I'm curious though, if you have the time: where in the python code did you get this error? Nice to know for possible future problems, & maybe there's a clue about not needing `--force` there but another solution if I start to play around with it & encounter the problem.

Comment: It was in the topology.py of the mysql utilities folder. In the try block where the error message ("Candidate slave is missing replication user") is reported, I noticed that the --force flag would bypass the error reporting

Comment: I should note that I have version 1.3.6 of the MySQL Utilities

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem while testing failover on some new clusters and noticed that after adding the `--force` flag as you suggest, the switchover completed successfully **and** created the user 'replication_user'@'S_NODE' without any prompting on my part.

It then occurred to me that the replication user I had set up was 'repl'@'specific_subnet_%' - which did not match what the script was looking for ('repl'@'S_NODE'), so the pre-check failed without `--force`.

I had another cluster I was testing, so to validate I did the following:

- ran the `mysqlrpladmin ... switchover` command without `--force` (it failed as expected)
- created both `'replication_user'@'S_NODE'` and `'replication_user'@'M_NODE'` with the same grant (`REPLICATION SLAVE`) and password as my existing replication_user. You need both S_NODE and M_NODE hosts if you want to be able to fail back and forth between them using this script.
- tried `mysqlrpladmin ... switchover` again without `--force`

It worked like a charm this time!

Moral of the story: the script expects the `'replication_user'@'new_master'` user to exist. The `--force` flag will create that user for you, and should not be necessary after the first time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, adding "--force" flag fixed the issue. More details in the comments above.
If anyone knows why this might be though, please comment.